# Windows 10 INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE After Cloning Drive

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have a new Kangaroo Mini PC (with dock) and wanted to use an SSD attached via the dock for Windows (instead of the built-in eMMC). I used TrueImage to clone the eMMC drive (with Windows 10) to the SSD.

When booting up on the SSD, it comes up with an INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error. Just after cloning, it let's me choose safe mode, and Windows does start up in safe mode.

However, it will not boot without safe mode. I tried several things using the command line recovery tool:

bootrec /FixBoot (these were intially returning "the system cannot find the file specified", until I made some changes with bcdedit

```
bootrec /FixMbr
```

`bootrec /RebuildBcd` (this returns 0 identified installations)

```
bootsect /force /nt60 ALL
```

deleting the eMMC partitions using diskpart -> clean

assigning the drive letters to C: and U: (for the fat32 partiton) via diskpart

changing the partitions to C: and U: via bcdedit

I couldn't delete C:\Boot\Bcd as some posts suggests, since I do not have a C:\Boot directory

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? The fact that it loads via safe mode suggests that there isn't any hardware issue. Could it be a driver issue?

All partitions from the original drive were copied. Here are screenshot of the volumes and EFI folder:

[image: EFI]

[image: VOLS]

Thanks!

Comment: When you cloned the drive what options in TrueImage did you use?  Did you select all the partitions?  It appears your that your partitions are in the wrong locations on the disk.

Comment: Yes, I selected the entire disk (all the partitions).

Comment: "until I made some changes with bcdedit" What changes?

Comment: The partition in Bcdedit was pointing to F: and I changed it to C:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by using the Restore Windows option in the Windows Recovery menu.